# XML Validation C# Localization

Tags: c#, xml, validation, localization, xsd

I am generating XML based upon some data. The culture is set to german, so the number is being generated in format 1087,1 (since in german they have commas instead of decimal).
The problem is that when i try to validate the XML, the validation fails as it expects the number to be in English format (1087.1) and considers 1087,1 as string rather than number.

Is there a way we can validate in german number format? OR Will I need to generate the XML in english number format? Following is the code i am using to validate XML

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas = xmlSchemaSet;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);

// Create the XmlReader object.
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Test.xml", settings);

while (reader.Read())
{
     if (!isXmlValid)
       break;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425341/xml-validation-vulnerable-to-culture-info

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to make XML nor XSD culture-aware - for e.g the spec for decimal type in XML states that "decimal has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) separated by a period as a decimal indicator.".  Your only solution if you want to use XSD to validate is to get the data in an unlocalised format.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I have to use Engish format as Xml takes period for floating point number and not comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rely on the built in data types (e.g. decimal) then it won't work for you simply because XSD's built-in lexical representation is by design culture invariant.

If you wish to stick to the way your numbers are generated, then you have to go with an XSD that uses custom made data types, essentially based on xsd:string. The downside is that you're missing on standard bindings which would use strong types...

Others may say to apply a transformation before consuming, basically interjecting custom processing to compensate for such lexical differences.